# Setting the svn root directory in Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

When I switch to another branch or tag I can't browse the available options in the repository. Subclipse says

> Could not find a repository
>
> svn: No repository found in 'svn://foo.com'

The repository is actually at svn://foo.com/bar. I can fetch the branches if I type in the full address by hand but it'd be nice to be able to choose from all available options. How do I tell Subclipse where the repository root is?

Comment: Did you fix this already (I hope so after 2 years :))?

Comment: As far as I can tell, it was simply not doable at the time. Perhaps it's possible in the latest versions of Eclipse/Subclipse, but I've switched to Git since then.

Answer (score 0):

Is `bar` a top level folder on the filesystem of the server?

If not, check that the server has been started correctly by specifying:

```
svnserve -d -r /path/to/repository/root
```

In this example, the full path to your repo would be `/path/to/repository/root/bar`.

Comment: The service is started with `-r /path/to/repository/root` which has several projects in it. The problem is that it looks like Subclipse looks in `root` and finds nothing when it should look in `root/bar`. I can't change the root to `root/bar` because then the other projects would be inaccessible.

Comment: Sorry, in that case I'm stuck. I know a bit about Subversion, but not familiar with Subclipse. Good luck in getting it sorted.